# Show that any ring with $3$ elements is commutative.

Tags: abstract-algebra, solution-verification

> Show that any ring with $3$ elements is commutative.

Suppose that $R$ is a ring with three elements $a,b$ and $c$. Then since $1_R$ an $0$ are both elements of $R$ we can assume wlog that $a=1_R, b=0.$ Now $ab = 1_R \cdot 0 = 0 \cdot 1_R = ba, ac = 1_R \cdot c = c \cdot 1_R = ca$ and $bc = 0 \cdot c = c \cdot 0 = cb$.

I suppose that this shows commutativity? Or am I misreading the problem and should consider that along with $1_R$ and $0$ I have three other elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no reason to assume that the assignment should be understood as the ring having $3$ elements other than $0$ and $1$.

If you're working under the definition "ring" = "ring with $1$", then what you did is correct and, if anything, the only thing that hasn't been assessed is ruling out $0=1$.

If you're working under "ring" = "rng", you still have the same result like this: $(R,+)$ is a (commutative) group of order $3$, therefore it is isomorphic to the cyclic group $\Bbb Z/3$. Therefore, if we call $\{0,a,b\}$ its elements, we have $a+a=b$. But then $ab=a^2+a^2=ba$, proving that multiplication is commutative.